# Halmos, Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces, Sec. 7, Ex. 8

Tags: linear-algebra

As a linear algebra refresher, I am working through the above cited text (2nd ed., 1958).  The exercise asks to determine the number of subsets of $\{0,1\}^3$ the are bases of $\mathbf{C}^3$ as a vector space over $\mathbf{C}$.  My approach was basically a somewhat smart enumeration:  List all the triplets (*i.e.*, sets of three vectors) where a 1 appears as a component in each position in at least one vector, then eliminate those triplets which are linearly dependent.

Two questions:

- Is there a more elegant method?  Is there an efficient way to do this for any dimension?
- I counted 29.  Is this correct?

Comment: What do you mean by $\{0,1\}^3$? Is it $\{0,1\}\times\{0,1\}\times\{0,1\}$? I suppose that the $0$ is the zero vector, but what is $1$? Is it the complex number $1+i\cdot 0$?

Comment: @Larara it's the set of vectors whose entries are either $0$ or $1$.  $0$ is the number $0 \in \Bbb C$.

Comment: Regarding the formatting stuff: there is a toolbar at the top which you can use to, among other things, italicize and bold.  Outside of that, get *italics* by `*typing between asterisks, like this*`, and get **bold** by `**typing between double asterisks, like this**`.  Hit enter twice for a paragraph break, two spaces and enter for a line break.

Answer (score 1):

First the set contains $8$ elements, of which $7$ can be used to form a basis (the set $(0,0,0)$ does not count).

So there are $\binom{7}{3} \, = 35$ the possible combinations.

A combination does not form a basis if one of the elements can be expressed as linear combination of the rest two of it. In this particular case, the only possibility is $v_1 = v_2 + v_3$ since the vectors are of component coefficients $0$ or $1$. Moreover, the two vectors $v_2$ and $v_3$ must be like $(0,0,1)$ and $(0,1,0)$ so that the sum does not have $2$ as component.

So there are merely $2$ possible situations.

1. $v_2$ and $v_3$ both have exactly one $1$ in their coordinates and in different places, like $(0,0,1)$ and $(0,1,0)$. There are $\binom{3}{2} = 3$ possibilities.
2. $v_2$ has one $1$ and $v_3$ has two $1$s in their coordinates, and the $1$s are in a totally complementary position, for example $(0,0,1)$ and $(1,1,0)$, so that they add up to $(1,1,1)$. There are $\binom{3}{1} = 3$ possibilities.

So the answer is $35 - 3 - 3 = 29$.

Comment: I'm not sure I am convinced that you can't have 1/2 as a scalar coefficient in a linear combination, so that you get (1/2)1 + (1/2)1 = 1.  Perhaps you can make that clear.  And, again, does this generalize to larger dimensions?  It seems to me it might be a hard combinatorial question.

Comment: Yeah I thought of that too. However if you take $0<\alpha<\beta<1$ such that $\alpha 1 + \beta 1 = 1$, then $\alpha 0 + \beta 1$ and $\alpha 1 + \beta 0$ cannot be integer. That means your $v_2$ and $v_3$ must be the same since they can only have same coefficient in same place. And that means they don't form a basis. This reasoning works for the $k$ sum too.

Comment: In higher dimensions, you could have -1 as well as +1 as coefficients, no?  Thanks for your contribution, by the way.

Comment: That is easy to avoid. You can just sort the equation $a_1v_1 + a_2 v_2 + a_3 v_3 = 0$ to the two sides so that the coefficients of each side are positive. And it is even easier to verify that the coefficients, after normalization, are between $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempt to invoke theory to solve this problem.

We have the following theorem.

**Theorem.** Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over a field $\Bbb R$ with $p$ elements. Then the number of linearly independent subsets of $V$ consisting of $m$ elements is
$$
\frac{1}{m!}\prod_{k=0}^{m-1}\left(p^n-p^k\right)\Box
$$

Since $V=\{0,1\}^3$ is a $\Bbb Z/2$-vector space the theorem implies that the number of $\Bbb Z/2$-bases of $\{0,1\}^3$ is
$$
\frac{1}{3!}\prod_{k=0}^2\left(2^3-2^k\right)=\frac{1}{3!}\left(2^3-2^0\right)\left(2^3-2^1\right)\left(2^3-2^2\right)=28
$$
Since any subset of $\{0,1\}^3$ that is a $\Bbb Z/2$-basis of $\{0,1\}^3$ is also a $\Bbb C$-basis of $\Bbb C^3$ we have $28$ as a lower-bound for our desired number.

Now, the above theorem implies that the number of $3\times 3$ matrices whose columns are subsets of $\{0,1\}^3$ with odd determinant is $3!\cdot 28$.

So, to finish our problem we need only count the number of $3\times 3$ matrices whose columns are subsets of $\{0,1\}^3$ with *even* determinant and divide by $3!$.